# spring security sasl: Unable to configure SSO url

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am using following spring security saml repo from github:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/master/sample

Whenever I try to update the SSO url, for e.g. localhost:8100/saml/ddo, instead of /saml/sso, browser gets stuck in infinite loops.
(I have followed the steps mentioned in readme and updated the url on okta as well in application to test)

Sample code and config enclosed in: 
[Spring secuirty saml issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/222)

**EDIT:**

I did what below answer suggested,but I am getting the **Incoming SAML message is invalid.**.

On debugging, I found that `attemptAuthentication` in `SAMLProcessingFilter`, the location in endpoint that are added still contain the `/api/saml/SSO` instead of `/api/saml/ddo`

[image]

[image]

and that's why `getEndpoint` method in `SamlUtil` throws excpetion with following line:

`throw new SAMLException("Endpoint with message binding " + messageBinding + " and URL " + requestURL + " wasn't found in local metadata");`

because the requestUrl and endpoint location do not match.

I also checked my `metadata.xml` but it does not contain any info related to these urls.

In the `MetaDataGenerator` class method `getSAMLWebSSOProcessingFilterPath`, the `samlWebSSOFilter` is null and that's why the default filter url: `/saml/SSO` is returned. I am trying to figure out how to set this value at runtime?
I understand that there is a method with name: `setSamlWebSSOFilter`, and everything works correct if I provide the url `/saml/ddo` at the time of startup. But I am not able to make this work if config is changed at runtime.

**Any idea how can I move forward?**

Comment: The property need to be set before the MetadataGenerator creates metadata for your service. You could use pre-configured metadata instead to fix the endpoints (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-sp-import). You of course need to update your IDP whenever the metadata changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting field `filterProcessesUrl` on bean `samlWebSSOProcessingFilter` to value `/saml/ddo` should solve the problem.

Comment: since the above comment is long, I have added it as part of my original Question